# Override the Local module directory for cvs using Hudson

Tags: java, module, cvs, hudson

I'm using Hudson and I need to change the checkout directory for cvs. Instead of checkout/update the project under the workspace dir, I'd like to specify a dir (as you can do for svn, changing the Local module directory conf) that will match the cvs tree structure.

Eg.

under cvs dir1/dir2/project
on my box workspace/dir1/dir2/project

is that possible with cvs and Hudson? Maybe there's a way to override the cvs call?

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -d option to define the folder via CVS...but as far as i know there should be a possibility to do that via Hudson as well...but my CVS times are far far away.

```
cvs -d CVSROOT checkout -d NewFolder ModuleName
```

Comment: Sorry. I've checked the CVS Plugin in Hudson it doesn't support different location in Workspace.

Comment: As i wrote above. Don't use CVS support in Hudson call CVS as a direct comment or put that into a script which called from Hudson instead.

Comment: Right I can do that and I've already done that. Using an external script, will I be able to see the differences between one build and another? Or I must use the cvs plugin?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Hudson you can override the working directory for free style jobs.

Go to the config for your job > Advanced Project Options > Use Custom Workspace.